# Localization on a SPField created in code

Tags: localization, spfield, resource-files

When you declare a SPField in CAML, you can add the localization in the code:

```
<Field
  ID="{57258F13-19B2-4A97-B244-090845B5C4AB}"
  Type="Text"
  Name="Partner"
  DisplayName="$Resources:MyProject,Partner"
  Group="MyProject Columns"
  StaticName="Partner"/>
```

However, some of the fields have to be created in code (e.g. External Data Columns). For these I also want localization. I found [this solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuserresource.setvalueforuiculture.aspx), but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add fields programmatically using [list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457586.aspx), providing CAML field definition with resource tokens in it.

Or you can wrap SetValueForUICulture in a nice helper method, and gain a capability to use it for any SPUserResource object. We're using this approach at work, and I would not say, that it is unclear or smth like this :) It's ok, just wrap it.

Comment: I tried with the AddFieldAsXml. The field takes the localization on list creation, however when changing language, it doesn't change (all other fields do).

Comment: Yep, a harsh detail. Haven't known about this. But what I do know undoubtedly, is that SetValueForUICulture will work properly with on-fly localization.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [SPUtility.GetLocalizedString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx)

Comment: I still got to push the localized string in some property, since I want the localization to change when the user changes his language in the browser, not only on provisioning.

Comment: Gotcha. Go for omlin's answer.